# Extract time using re in python

Tags: python, regex

How can I  extract the time from the following array?
Right now I am trying with `re`

```
data = ['Mys--dreyn M (00:07:04): Yes', ' of course.\r\n']
time_search = re.search('(*)', "".join(data), re.IGNORECASE)
if time_search:
    time = time_search.group(1)
    print time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix `re` expression:

```
time_search = re.search('\((.*)\)', "".join(data), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative way to extract the time - use the [`dateutil.parser`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) in the "fuzzy" mode:

```
In [1]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [2]: s = "'Mys--dreyn M (00:07:04): Yes', ' of course.\r\n'"

In [3]: dt = parse(s, fuzzy=True)  # dt is a 'datetime' object

In [4]: dt.hour
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: dt.minute
Out[5]: 7

In [6]: dt.second
Out[6]: 4
```

---

And, as far as your regular expression goes, I'd improve it by checking the digit pairs as well:

```
time_search = re.search('\((\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\)', "".join(data), re.IGNORECASE)
```